# What about a find-a-fallacy challenge?

Tags: discussion

Hermeneutics has good practices as well as bad practices. Most of these bad practices can be grouped together in families. Would a good challenge be to find a verse with a published fallacious interpretation and ask the site to identify the fallacy?

Comment: I see that we recently had the question [A word for the fallacy of assuming whatever brings God the most glory is the correct interpretation a text?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/4270/68 "Currently unanswered.")  Personally, I'd prefer if the question were more neutral on whether or not the hermeneutical approach is fallacious or not.